# SARIMAX statsmodel weird error in Databricks

Tags: pyspark, databricks, statsmodels

I'm running a grid search optimazation o a Databricks notebook, the same code runs on my local machine but when I try to run in on Databricks I get a TypeError as follow:

```
TypeError: ufunc 'isnan' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''
```

The fitting process I'm running is this (note this has defined p,d,q,P,D,Q,m values as I need to check why none model are being fitted):

```
exodus_train = np.array(np.random.normal(2,1, size=(25,1)))
model = sm.tsa.statespace.SARIMAX(train,
                            order=[2,0,0],
                            exog=exodus_train,
                            seasonal_order=[2,0,0,12],
                            enforce_stationarity=False,
                            enforce_invertibility=False).fit()
```

Than it trow an TypeError:

````
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<command-1275539631463044> in <module>
      4                                 seasonal_order=[2,0,0,12],
      5                                 enforce_stationarity=False,
----> 6                                 enforce_invertibility=False).fit()

/databricks/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/statsmodels/tsa/statespace/mlemodel.py in fit(self, start_params, transformed, cov_type, cov_kwds, method, maxiter, full_output, disp, callback, return_params, optim_score, optim_complex_step, optim_hessian, flags, **kwargs)
    430         """
    431         if start_params is None:
--> 432             start_params = self.start_params
    433             transformed = True
    434 

/databricks/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/statsmodels/tsa/statespace/sarimax.py in start_params(self)
    966         # Although the Kalman filter can deal with missing values in endog,
    967         # conditional sum of squares cannot
--> 968         if np.any(np.isnan(endog)):
    969             mask = ~np.isnan(endog).squeeze()
    970             endog = endog[mask]

TypeError: ufunc 'isnan' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''  ```
````

Answer (score 0):

In case this happens with someone else, this will happen if your time series value has commas as decimal separator or if you column is not a float.